# Determine binomial or trinomial distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A fair six-sided die is rolled 30 independent times, let X be the number of ones and Y the number of twos.

What is the joint PMF of X and Y?

> Question: Should I think of this as binomial distribution or trinomial and why? It seems like trinomial since there is number of one, number of two and the rest numbers as three categories. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^{N}$ be the sample space. If for a given $\omega\in\Omega$, $X(\omega)=n$ and $Y(\omega)=m$, then $\mathbb P(\{\omega\}) = \left(\frac16\right)^{n+m}\left(\frac23\right)^{N-n-m}$. There are $\binom Nn\binom{N-n}m$ outcomes with $X(\omega)=n$ and $Y(\omega)=m$, and hence
$$
\mathbb P(X=n,Y=m) = \binom Nn\binom{N-n}m \left(\frac16\right)^{n+m}\left(\frac23\right)^{N-n-m},\ \ n,m\geqslant 0, n+m\leqslant N.
$$

Comment: For the outcomes, how do we count the rest of the (N-n-m) outcomes just cancels out by $\binom{N-n-m}{N-n-m}$?

Comment: @neveryield I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: For P(X=n,Y=m), how about the rest of the N-n-m objects, how do you count them? Do we count by $\binom{N-n-m}{N-n-m}$ so that they are cancelled?

Comment: They don't need to be counted. We're only interested in the outcomes corresponding to $\{X=n,Y=m\}$ - not the rest of the outcomes. Otherwise we'd be counting *every* outcome, which clearly would not be correct.